# ZipArchive skipping over files 49-100

Tags: ios, swift, php-ziparchive

I have a function that is supposed to create a batch of files, write them to a directory, zip that directory, and attach it to an email.

When I run it, it tells me that it has written 299 files, but when I open up the zip folder precisely 50 are missing

Here is the code. I thought about trimming it down, but I was afraid of removing something that might help someone spot the problem:

```
func exportAllData() {
    var totalExports = 0

    // fetch all the data first
    // 1 Describe what you want
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Fish")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "time", ascending: false)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    // 2 Get it!
    do {

        let allCatches = try managedContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [NSManagedObject]
        totalExports = allCatches!.count

        // Create a folder to store the catches in
        // path to where data will be written
        let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
        let applicationDocumentsDirectory:NSURL = urls[urls.count-1]
        let destinationURL = applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("filesToExport", isDirectory: true)
        do { try NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtURL(destinationURL, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
            print("created directory")

            var currentFile = 0

            // Write each fish to file
            for fish in allCatches! {

                currentFile+= 1

                // convert NSManagedObject into a Dictionary, serialize it to NSData, and write it to file
                let keys = fish.entity.propertiesByName.keys.array
                let dictionary = fish.dictionaryWithValuesForKeys(keys)
                let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(dictionary)

                let fileName = "catchNumber\(currentFile)"
                let fileURL  = destinationURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)

                let success = data.writeToFile(fileURL.path!, atomically: false)
                if success { print("successfully exported: "+fileName) } else { print("FAILED to export: "+fileName) }
            }

            // DEBUG
            do {
                let contents = try NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(destinationURL.path!)
                print(contents)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }

            // After all the fish have been written to file, zip the file
            let zipURL = applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("exported.zip")
            Main.createZipFileAtPath(zipURL.path!, withContentsOfDirectory: destinationURL.path!)

            // Load the zip file up as data and send it out in an email
            let zipData = NSData(contentsOfURL: zipURL)

            let picker = MFMailComposeViewController()
            picker.mailComposeDelegate = self
            picker.setSubject("Shared Catch Log! (\(totalExports) entries)")
            picker.setMessageBody("Open the attachment to this email on an iOS device with Catch Stats installed on it to import all catch into your Catch Log!", isHTML: false)
            picker.addAttachmentData(zipData!, mimeType: "applcation/CatchStats", fileName: "CatchStatsLog.csl")
            presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)

        // If failed to created directory
        } catch {
            print("directory already existed")
        }

    // If failed to execute fetch request
    } catch {
        print(error)
        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
}
```

Now, at the `//Debug` when I check the contents of the folder I'm about to zip, it has 299 files numbered from 1 to 299 in it.

But when I email the file out and open it up, 50-99 are all missing. Can anybody offer me some advice?

I plucked this code out of ZipArchive's Main.m file. This is what it's doing.

```
    + (BOOL)createZipFileAtPath:(NSString *)path
withContentsOfDirectory:(NSString *)directoryPath {
return [self createZipFileAtPath:path withContentsOfDirectory:directoryPath keepParentDirectory:NO];
}

+ (BOOL)createZipFileAtPath:(NSString *)path
withContentsOfDirectory:(NSString *)directoryPath
    keepParentDirectory:(BOOL)keepParentDirectory {
BOOL success = NO;
NSFileManager *fileManager = nil;
Main *zipArchive = [[Main alloc] initWithPath:path];

if ([zipArchive open]) {
    // Use a local file manager (queue/thread compatibility)
    fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];

    NSDirectoryEnumerator *directoryEnumerator = [fileManager enumeratorAtPath:directoryPath];
    NSString *fileName;

    while ((fileName = [directoryEnumerator nextObject])) {
        BOOL isDirectory;
        NSString *fullFilePath = [directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
        [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:fullFilePath isDirectory:&isDirectory];

        if (!isDirectory) {
            if (keepParentDirectory) {
                fileName = [[directoryPath lastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
            }

            [zipArchive writeFileAtPath:fullFilePath withFileName:fileName];
        } else {
            if (0 == [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:fullFilePath error:nil].count) {
                NSString *temporaryName = [fullFilePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@".DS_Store"];
                [@"" writeToFile:temporaryName atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
                [zipArchive writeFileAtPath:temporaryName withFileName:[fileName stringByAppendingPathComponent:@".DS_Store"]];
                [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:temporaryName error:nil];
            }
        }
    }

    success = [zipArchive close];
}

return success;
```

}

Comment: Please show the code of createZipFileAtPath.

Comment: Thanks, I added the code from ZipArchive.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, but it is more of a work around. After a lot of testing, I realized that ZipArchive would fail to zip a folder with an more than 250 files in it. It didn't matter what the files were named or the order they were in.

Instead of serializing each NSDictionary and writing it to file, I created an array of NSDictionaries, and serialized that instead.That way ZipArchive only had to zip one file, and it seems to be working fine now.